# Propublica API authenticate key with javascript

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, key, endpoint

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I'm trying to send a GET request to the [ProPublica API](https://propublica.github.io/congress-api-docs/#lists-of-members). They gave me a key, but the documentation does not say how to authenticate with this key when I try and hit the endpoints of the API. If anyone can make sense of this, I'd appreciate it!

I would like to hit this route:

```
GET https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/{chamber}/{state}/current.json
```

The documentation only mentions curl:

```
curl "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/senate/RI/current.json"
  -H "X-API-Key: PROPUBLICA_API_KEY"
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Amol for the reply, here is a working version that writes to the console. Make sure you have jQuery, or test it in a browser's dev tools on a site that has jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
         url: "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/senate/RI/current.json",
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'json',
         headers: {'X-API-Key': 'YOUR KEY HERE'}
       }).done(function(data){
       console.log(data)
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

try to used this

```
$.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost/PlatformPortal/Buyers/Account/SignIn",
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'json',
         headers: {'X-API-Key', 'PROPUBLICA_API_KEY'}
       });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will amend the post slightly, because instead of a comma, it was a colon. You are awesome!