# How do I add my API key to this URL for successful GET?

Tags: javascript, api

I have a API key for the following: https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/116/house/members.json
and I am looking to be able to (in Javascript) code a user input that returns a value from the JSON.

I am not sure where or how to put my API key in the URL to get a successful return. Currently the error message I get is "unauthorized".
Any help would be great!

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/#overview)

Comment: Always read documentation before implementing anything 

https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/#authentication

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Propublica API authenticate key with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109625/propublica-api-authenticate-key-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use Fetch API (JS) and pass it on the headers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options

And here is what you should include on the header: https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/#authentication